# Evaluating Real and Imaginary parts in a dispersion equation via ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to reproduce a dispersion curve from P. Zou's thesis found here: http://www.ipd.anl.gov/anlpubs/2001/06/39620.pdf on Pg. 31, Eq. 2.13.

The problem is, the code below only gives values for the real part (`vp > c`) of the wave vectors `k1, k2` shown below, but I am also interested in the `vp < c` portion of the curve (see P. Zou's figure 2.2 on Pg. 33). Is there a way to plot the full dispersion curve for complex wave vectors `k1`, and `k2`?

```
Clear[vp, ω]
a = 2.96*^-3;
b = 4.53*^-3;
ϵ0 = 8.8541878*^-12;
ϵr = 20;
clight = 299792458;
k1[ω_, vp_] = ω*Sqrt[1/clight^2 - 1/vp^2];
k2[ω_, vp_] = ω*Sqrt[ϵr/clight^2 - 1/vp^2];
BJ1[n_, r_, ω_, vp_] = BesselJ[n, k1[ω, vp]*r];
BY1[n_, r_, ω_, vp_] = BesselY[n, k1[ω, vp]*r];
BJ2[n_, r_, ω_, vp_] = BesselJ[n, k2[ω, vp]*r];
BY2[n_, r_, ω_, vp_] = BesselY[n, k2[ω, vp]*r];
F[n_, r_, ω_, vp_] = 
  BesselJ[n, k2[ω, vp]*r] - 
    BesselJ[n, k2[ω, vp]*b]*BesselY[n, k2[ω, vp]*r]/BesselY[n,k2[ω, vp]*b];
FP[n_, r_, ω_, vp_] = 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][BJ2][n, r, ω, vp] - 
    BesselJ[n, k2[ω, vp]*b]/BesselY[n, k2[ω, vp]*b]*
      Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][BY2][n, r, ω, vp];
disp = 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][BJ1][0, a, ω,vp]/(k1[ω, vp]*a*BesselJ[0, k1[ω, vp]*a]) == 
    ϵr*FP[0, a, ω, vp]/(k2[ω, vp]*a*F[0, a, ω, vp]);
ContourPlot[Evaluate[disp], {vp, .3 clight, 2. clight}, {ω, 2 Pi*9*^9, 2 Pi*15*^9}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"vp", "ω"}, MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 5, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to be certain about the issue. What are the "strange features"? Please post a minimum working example.

Comment: I've updated the question and provided my code; thanks for any help.

Comment: The single lines `rD2;` and `rD3;` do not do anything.  Deleting these lines will not solve your problem but will clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Yes I agree, this was for debugging purposes for the ListPlot issue in the last line.  I'm running 9.0.0 BTW

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions @Jens ?

Comment: You're aware that `k1` is always pure imaginary if `vp` is a velocity?

Comment: vp is the phase velocity and not necessarily less than c.  And what impact would this information have onto the problem?

Comment: I would suggest that you clean up the code a bit to focus on the parts that give you trouble (e.g. the `rD2;` lines, and `cdata`, which is not used for plotting): I for one am a bit confused as to what exactly your *Mathematica* problem is here, so you might want to re-edit your question to clarify and prune it. For your bonus question, that depends on the structure of the `Cases` result, which is a always list of lists. Adding a `First@` in front of `Cases` in your current definition of `rD` should fix that issue.

Comment: Okay I've reedited the question to make it simpler and to the point.  I still would appreciate any help or suggestions towards solving the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It seems clear to me that you need to plot the contours of a different equation, but what it is cannot be answered without looking at the paper. Unfortunately, this is then no longer a *Mathematica* issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: The issue is that mathematica is not solving the complex equation, only real; this is obvious when you add Re[ ] to both sides of the `disp` equation.  How does ContourPlot solve the contour curve anyway?